# DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_quantize_training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi developers and programmers, I'm try to import keras module and it show error, please help, Thank you.

code

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
```

error

```
DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_quantize_training
```

I have try to reinstall keras and it show error below, im not is this causing the problem

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.10.0 requires keras<2.11,>=2.10.0, but you have keras 2.11.0 which is incompatible.tensorflow 2.10.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.11,>=2.10.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.11.0 which is incompatible
```

im using vscode, xampp

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself, its the version compatible, i uninstall keras and tensorflow, then reinstall tensorflow by the version of 2.10 and it work